# Ajax posting form data for Codeigniter validation

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have an ajax form set up where I have am passing the fields to my Codeigniter controller to process. My ajax looks like this:

```
...
dataType : 'json',
data : {
   'name' : $('#name_recipe').val(),
   'email' : $('#email').val(),   
   'town' : $('#town').val()
}, success : function (data, status){
   if(data.status != 'error') {
      $('#name').val('');
      $('#email').val('');
      $('#town').val('');
   }
   $('#response').html('<p>'+data.msg+'</p>');
}
```

and in my Controller I process them separately, for example:

```
if(empty($_POST['name'])) {
   $status = "error";
   $msg = "The <b>Name</b> field is required.";
} else {
   $name = $_POST['name'];
}

echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
```

However, this processes the error messages one by one and what I would really like is to push them in an array so I can show them all at once. How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should be accessing your form variables using codeigniters `input` object.

I created an array to store messages. If an error was encountered a message was pushed onto the array.  Once all checks are complete, if the `$msg` array size is greater than zero we know an error occurred.

**PHP**

```
$msg = array();

$name = $this->input->post('name');
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$town = $this->input->post('town');

if (!$name) {
    $msg[] = '<p>The <b>Name</b> field is required';
}
if (!email || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $msg[] = '<p>The <b>Email</b> field is not valid';
}
if (!$town) {
    $msg[] = '<p>The <b>Town</b> field is required';
}

$status = count($msg) ? 'error' : 'success';

echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
```

**Javascript in Success Callback**

On the client side, we create an unordered list of every error and append that to `#response`.

```
var list = $('<ul />').appendTo($('#response').empty());
for (var e in data.msg) {
    $('<li />', {text: data.msg[e]}).appendTo(list);
}
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! You have no idea the headache you have saved me :) thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

your Controller:

```
# validate (recommend Ci validation)
$msg = '';
if (!$name) $msg .= 'The name field is required<br />';
if (!email || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $msg .= 'The Email field is not valid <br />';
if (!$town) $msg .= 'The Town field is required<br />';

if($msg != '') exit($msg);

# process
$this->my_model->process();

exit('success');
```

JS:

```
...
success : function (data) {
   if(data == 'success') {
      $('#name').val('');
      $('#email').val('');
      $('#town').val('');
   } else {
      $('#response').html(data);
   }
}
```